# How to run redis container with persist volume

Tags: docker

with docker-compose I know how to do that:

```
version: '3.0'

services:

  redis:

    image: redis

    volumes:

      - redis_data:/data

volumes:

  redis_data:
```

How to run the same without dockerfile/compose file?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With plain Docker, you use the `-v` option:

```
docker run -v redis_data:/data redis
```

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) you can find more on this.

Comment: Should I create a volume first?

Comment: The command will automatically create a volume for you if it doesn't exist. You can check that with `docker volume ls`; there will be a `redis_data` entry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 -v redis_data:/data --name rds redis
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using `docker-compose`, use `external` option for volume:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data

volumes:
  redis_data:
    external: false
```

From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external):

> If set to true, specifies that this volume has been created outside of
>   Compose. docker-compose up does not attempt to create it, and raises
>   an error if it doesn’t exist.